# Raw pointer's data disappearing

Tags: rust

Consider the code below:

```
struct Person {
  mate: Option<*const Person>,
  siblings: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Person {
  fn meets(&mut self, mate: &mut Person) {
    self.mate = Some(mate);
    mate.mate = Some(self); 
  }
}

struct Bar {
  person: Person,
}

impl Bar {
  fn addr(&self) {
    unsafe {
      println!("\n`bob.siblings.len()`: {}, `bob.susan.siblings.len()`: {}", 
        self.person.siblings.len(), (*self.person.mate.unwrap()).siblings.len());

      println!("\n but wait -> `bob.susan.bob.siblings.len()`: {} ??", 
        (*(*self.person.mate.unwrap()).mate.unwrap()).siblings.len());

      println!("\nthis is `bob.susan.bob's address`: {:p} => same address inside bar ???", 
        (*self.person.mate.unwrap()).mate.unwrap());
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let mut bob = Person {
    mate: None,
    siblings: {
      let mut stuff: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
      unsafe {
        stuff.set_len(2);
      }
      stuff
    }
  };

  let mut susan = Person { 
    mate: None, 
    siblings: {
      let mut stuff: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
      unsafe {
        stuff.set_len(4);
      }
      stuff
    } 
  };

  bob.meets(&mut susan);

  println!("\nbob has {} `siblings` before entering the `bar`.", bob.siblings.len());
  println!("\nthis is bob's address: {:p}", &bob);
  let bar = Bar { person: bob };
  bar.addr();
}
```

The result:

```
bob has 2 `siblings` before entering the `bar`.

this is bob's address: 0x7fff556ab470

`bob.siblings.len()`: 2, `bob.susan.siblings.len()`: 4

 but wait -> `bob.susan.bob.siblings.len()`: 0 ??

this is `bob.susan.bob's address`: 0x7fff556ab470 => same address inside bar ???
```

---

My question is, where did `bob.siblings` go? Even though I'm calling `bob.siblings` through `susan` (`bob.mate.mate.siblings` -> `bob.susan.bob.siblings`), shouldn't the result be the same?

How can I call `bob.susan.bob.siblings` and get the same result as if I had called `bob.siblings`?

Rust version: `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (270a677d4 2015-03-07) (built 2015-03-07)`

Comment: There is no need for `Option<*T>`. Check out [nullable pointer optimization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#the-"nullable-pointer-optimization")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This would be a good example of what Rust helps prevent, but you've deliberately turned off the safety checks, and now we are back to C. Check this line:

```
let bar = Bar { person: bob };
```

This line *moves* the data stored in `bob` into `bar`. This means that the pointer has been **invalidated** and you can't trust any of the values. Let's add this afterwards:

```
println!("\nthis is bob's address: {:p}", &bob);
let bar = Bar { person: bob };
println!("\nthis is the bar's address: {:p}", &bar);
println!("\nthis is bob's new address: {:p}", &bar.person);

// this is bob's address:     0x7fffe10518c0
// this is the bar's address: 0x7fffe10517d0
// this is bob's new address: 0x7fffe10517d0
```

You are in for a world of hurt now, as you try to wrangle which pointers are correct and which aren't!

One way to solve this is to not move `bob`. Instead, take a reference:

```
struct Bar<'a> {
  person: &'a Person,
}
// ...
let bar = Bar { person: &bob };
```

Another would be to call `meets` *after* moving it into the `bar`:

```
let mut bar = Bar { person: bob };
bar.person.meets(&mut susan);
```

Another would be to `Box` (or use `Arena`) the the data. Then the data is not allocated on the stack and so the value's address doesn't change when it is moved:

```
struct Bar {
    person: Box<Person>,
}
// ...
let mut bob = Box::new(Person { });
let mut susan = Box::new(Person { });
```

Comment: I guess there is no way to achieve what I'm trying to do..? (reach the **correct** `bob` through `susan`  (`bob.mate.mate` or `bob.susan.bob`)

Comment: @goo I wouldn't say *no* way, you just have to be more careful. I've added some potential solutions.

Comment: I switched the raw pointers to` Box` and now I'm getting `cannot move out of borrowed content` and `use of moved value:` errors everywhere.

Comment: @goo for the `Box` example, the `mate` field is still a raw pointer. Only the constructed people (`bob`, `susan`) and `Bar` use `Box`.